# Why my getRequest() in saga doesn't see data from json.db after postRequest

Tags: javascript, react-redux, fetch, redux-saga, saga

My saga.ts :

```
export function* postSomething(object:object){  
        yield postRequest(object);
        const Objects=yield getRequest();
        console.log(Objects); 
        yield put(showObject(Objects));
}
```

**db.json is my little database

My db.json is empty at the beginning, and after first postRequest(object), db.json will have one object,but when I try to get that object with getRequest I get [ ] (empty array)!?***Why?***

My console.log(Object) doesn't print anything.

Next time when I do postRequest(object) and post to my db.json one more object, that means db.json will have two objects, but after that, when I try to pull objects with getRequest(), my console.log print only one object?***Why?***

How to get all objects from db.json after postRequest() ?

postRequest(object)(post object to db.json using fetch,method "post") is service function which communicate with db.json,

getRequest()( fetch(url) which need to return all object from db.json )
.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generator function so every time it returns it restarts after the last yield statement so the second time through, it starts at line 3.

Redux saga has the call effect:

```
import {call, put} from 'redux-saga/effects';

export function* postSomething(object:object){  
        yield call(postRequest, object);
        const Objects=yield call(getRequest());
        console.log(Objects); 
        yield put(showObject(Objects));
}
```

In your case, though, it seems like you should probably be using 2 chained sagas here.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `call` effect from `redux-saga` API:

```
export function* postSomething(object:object){  
        yield call(postRequest(object));
        const Objects = yield call(getRequest());
        console.log(Objects); 
        yield put(showObject(Objects));
}
```

In general, it would be better pattern using 2 different sagas for handling each request. that way you can handle success/failure with `redux` in much more ease and clarity.